# Установка непрерывного соединения с сервером

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.Есть код, он отправляет hello при помощи веб сокетов на сервер и сразу заканчивает соединение. Я пытаюсь сделать что бы соединение не прерывалось а продолжало слушать и ждать следующего сообщения. 
Вот код:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button start;
    private TextView out;
    private OkHttpClient client;
    private  final class Echo extends WebSocketListener{
        private static final int NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS = 1000;
        @Override
        public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
           webSocket.send("hello");

        webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS,"bye");
        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(WebSocket webSocket, String text) {
            out("R"+text);
        }



        @Override
        public void onFailure(WebSocket webSocket, Throwable t, Response response) {
            out("error"+t.getMessage());
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        start =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        out=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        client= new OkHttpClient();



        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                start();
            }
        });

    }
    private void start(){

       Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://адрес:8081").build();
        Echo listener = new Echo();
       WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);

       //client.dispatcher().executorService().shutdown();
    }

private void out(final String txt){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            out.setText(out.getText().toString()+"\n\n"+ txt);
        }
    });

}

}
```

Я попытался удалить строку         `webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS,"bye");`   это сработало но при каждом следующем нажатии на кнопку "отправить" количество сообщений "hello" увеличивалось на одно, т.е нажимаю один раз, отправляется 2 сообщения, нажимаю еще раз - отправляется 3 . Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Comment: Если Вы хотите действительно непрерывное соединение — работу с сокетом нужно вынести в `Service`. При повороте экрана или сворачивании приложения (тут 50 на 50), активность умрет.

Comment: А также стоит учесть, что непрерывно открытое соединение высаживает батарею с неприятно большой скоростью.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока не пришел кто-то поумнее, предложу вам эксперимент:

```
    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket webSocket, Response response) {
       int i = 0;
       webSocket.send("hello" + i++);
       webSocket.send("hello" + i);

    webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS,"bye");
    }
```

Сделайте так и нажмите 2-3 раза. Мне интересно, сокет хранит в буфере сообщения и дублирует их, или какая-нибудь часть кода вызывает метод 2 раза.

---

Попробуйте удалить webSocket.close(NORMAL_CLOSURE_STATUS,"bye"); можно вынести в `onClosed` или `onClosing`.

Потом

```
   Request request = new Request.Builder().url("ws://адрес:8081").build();
    Echo listener = new Echo();
   WebSocket ws = client.newWebSocket(request, listener);
```

вынесете в переменные класса, т.к. при каждом нажатии у вас создаются новые объекты и видимо WebSocketListener обрабатывает все доступные WebSocket.

Comment: Ну вообщем оно отправляет hello 0 hello1 в любом случае, больше 1 нет

Comment: тогда получается, что метод вызывается 2 раза, а не WebSocket кеширует и отправляет повторно. Попробуйте дебагером пройтись и посмотреть в какие моменты происходит лишний вызов

Comment: @xcfr дополнил ответ  - попробуйте